# "Feeding" data or "entering" data: which one is correct?

Tags: differences, verbs, writing, computing

Which is the better verb to use with *data*: *feeding* or *entering*?

Furthermore, which is more common in the
literature of the field and which do people who
work in the field say more often?

Are they used for
different kinds of input systems? If the data are
automatically continuously input by a machine (e.g., the Mars probe), is feeding data used, but if
the data are individually input by someone at a
keyboard (e.g., entering data into a user
database), is entering data used?

Comment: Both are correct in the context of grammar.

Comment: More important is "_Which is more common in the literature of the field and which do people who work in the field say more often?_" Another relevant question is whether they are used for different kinds of input systems. If the data are automatically continuously input by a machine (e.g., the Mars probe), is _feeding data_ used, but if the data are individually input by someone at a keyboard (e.g., entering data into a user database), is _entering data_ used? I don't know. Do you?

Comment: This question is collecting downvotes because it's too vague. As @Bill implies, and as I'm certain is the case, different contexts normally use different words. Also don't forget that in the modern world, the very *concept* of entering/feeding data into systems is becoming a bit outdated. These days, the systems themselves are more likely to include *data collection* components - like fledged chicks, they go out and get their own "food", rather than waiting to be "fed".

Comment: This is a right question asked in the wrong place. Should try SO.

Comment: I've expanded the question with Bill Franke's suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

Entering data is more appropriate when talking about inserting data into something (such as a spreadsheet or database) where it can be used later. Feeding data is more appropriate when utilizing data, such as in a computer program or report generator.

Your examples for the Mars Probe and a data entry person are correct. The probe sensors are feeding information to NASA. The person entering data on the computer is, well, entering data.

Using [Google's ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feeding%20data,entering%20data&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to determine which is more common in literature:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feed?q=feed),

> **Feed:** (2)Supply with material or power: *a radial circuit fed by a 20 amp fuse*
>   (3)put into a machine: *the programs are fed into the computer*

I suggest using the word *feed* only when the data is going to be consumed and processed by the system. If the data is being put in just for  storage or archiving, *insert* or *enter* would be more appropriate.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the OED and not Oxford Dictionaries Pro?

Comment: I meant OED online. http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feed?q=feed

Comment: A down vote and no explanation, *disappointing*!

Comment: It’s a little confusing, but the online version of the OED is here: http://www.oed.com/

Comment: @BarrieEngland: If you go to the bottom right to the page you'll find a section titled **More from Oxford**, under which is the link to **Oxford Dictionaries Online** [http://oxforddictionaries.com/]. Feel free to search any word there. Hope there remains no confusion.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online and the Oxford English Dictionary are different publications.

Comment: I fail to understand, how? Especially since, oxforddictionaries.com/ is listed under  oed.com. Anyways, an edit has been made to my answer and this discussion isn't of much relevance to the OP's question.

Comment: The OED requires a paid subscription.

Comment: Commonly, feeding data implies something that is automatically input into a system, while entering implies data input into a system by hand. Both are grammatically correct.

Comment: @Barrie -- is the paid version of the OED online available from many libraries the same content as the OED?

Comment: @Chris. Do you mean the same content as in the printed version? I haven't compared the two, but I suspect anyone with a serious interest in English will only use the online version. That's because it's easier to use, and because it's subject to a rolling programme of revision.

Comment: That's what I meant. If the free version is a lesser version, I was curious if the paid online version was the equivalent of the paper books. I assume it is!

Comment: @Chris: It need not be that data *fed* into a system is being done so *automatically*. If you read definition **(3)** in my answer it would occur to you that *programs* are not fed automatically to the system, someone has to do that manually too(*coz otherwise I'd be on the streets!*). ;)

Comment: I was speaking of popular usage as I have experienced it in my time working with technology. It isn't 100%, of course, by in my experience when someone says that data was fed into the system they are referring to automatic means... which is why I made a comment rather than proposing an answer!

Comment: @Chris: The online OED is more up-to-date than the printed OED. "The most up-to-date version of the OED is the
complicatedly composite version of the Dictionary
which can be browsed and searched at www.oed.com... This version is in effect the THIRD EDITION of the
OED (OED3)." http://oed.hertford.ox.ac.uk/main/content/view/429/479/ It will take at least a decade to  complete the OED3 and it probably won't be printed: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/booknews/7970391/Oxford-English-Dictionary-will-not-be-printed-again.html